# How i can use a CreateView with the same model Post to create a Post(Parent) and comments Post(Children)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Im trying to create a view to use it in two cases:

- Create a Post
- Create a Post with comment.

Using the same model and view (Im open to use two views, but im looking for the Pythonic/Django way to do it). I dont know to do it with CBV -> CreateView

Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="user/post", blank=True)
    video = models.URLField(blank=True)
    comment = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True, related_name='comments')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

View:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = "core/post_create.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.date_created = timezone.now()
        obj.save()
        return redirect("feed")
```

[Source code on Github](https://github.com/cotizcesar/ordis/tree/develop/core)

Answer (score 0):

Comment is a Foreign Key to  "self" , so inside form_valid

```
 def form_valid(self, form):      
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        if comment: //check if comment entered using form
            comment = Post.objects.create(**) // Create comment using the required form values
            obj.comment = comment
        obj.date_created = timezone.now()
        obj.save()
        return redirect("feed")
```